# Convert db date to rfc3339

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that collects datetime as follows: 2013-05-21 00:00:00 UTC

This needs to be converted to a XML compatible format. I tried using the `.rfc3339` method:

```
DateTime.rfc3339('2013-05-21 00:00:00 UTC')
```

I get the following error: `convert ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone to String`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateTime::rfc3339` *class method* parses an RFC3339 string and returns a date object. To convert a date object into an RFC3339 string, use the following code:

```
DateTime.parse('2013-05-21 00:00:00 UTC').rfc3339
```