# Rails convert updated_at to rfc3339 format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to convert the standard rails DB fields created_at and updated_at into the atom feed rfc3339 format. So far I have tried:

```
DateTime.rfc3339(issue.updated_at)
```

and

```
DateTime.parse(issue.updated_at).rfc3339
```

and both times I get:

```
no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into String
```

If I try and validate my atom feed at w3.org I get the following message:

```
updated must be an RFC-3339 date-time: 2013-06-27 13:42:34 UTC
```

The above error is for all the database updated_at fields. When I create the feed updated at field like the following I get no error:

```
xml.updated(Time.now.xmlschema)
```

I've searched high and low without fixing this issue. I did find [Convert db date to rfc3339](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486525/convert-db-date-to-rfc3339) but that didn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try:

```
issue.updated_at.to_datetime.rfc3339
```